# Infinite loop due to an Array issue

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class trothBrthdays {

    public static void main ( String args [] ) {
        Random day = new Random();
        int days[] = new int[366];
        int smallest = 0;
        int largest = 885000;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 885000; i++)
        {
            int persons = day.nextInt(365) + 1;
            days[persons] += 1;
        }
        for (int a = 1; a <= 365; a++)
        {
            System.out.printf ( " \nDay %d: %d ", a, days[a]);
        }
```

Here program finds day with most birthdays on it

```
        for (int b = 0; b < days.length;)
        {
            if(days[b] > smallest)
            {
                largest = days[b];
                System.out.printf ( "\nLargest: %d ", days[b]);
            }
        }
```

Here program finds day with least birthdays on it

```
        for (int c = 0; c > days.length;)
        {
            if (days[c] < largest)
            {
                smallest = days[c];
                System.out.printf ( "\nSmallest: %d ", days[c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when the program gets to finding the largest number it infinitely loops the largest number and I can't figure out why. I'm still a Beginner program and would love constructive criticism on how to format and type this program.

Comment: your code is horribly formatted, but in the bottom section b and c are not incremented.  However, you haven't really asked a question -- just presented code.

Comment: your tag is misleading

Comment: The way you've written your loop, why would you expect it to ever terminate?

Comment: There are actually two problems with the code, but my answer at least solves the infinite for loop problem. :3

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because of your for loops:

```
for (int b = 0; b < days.length;)
```

The construction of a `for` loop is in three parts. Part one is the iterator's declaration:

```
(int b = 0;
```

part two is the break condition. That is, what condition must be met, else the loop breaks.

```
b < days.length;
```

finally, the third part determines what should change between each iteration. But your for loop is missing that part. It should be...

```
b++)
```

Edit:

The second problem that you have is that this will not work with the code as it is written. But I suppose that will be an exercise for you to figure out why.

Comment: I originally had the b++), but when i did the largest part of the program then just restates all of the randomly generated numbers.

Comment: that would be the second problem you have to solve. Take a close look at the `if` statements inside your loops.

Comment: One could have placed the breaking condition in the body of the loop - since the iteration step is not required in a for loop (in fact, none of them are) - but otherwise, you're spot-on.

Comment: So if I'm reading my code right the If statement states that the days[b] will always be greater then smallest so it infinitely loops, which would be the problem. I can't figure out a way to get around that, but it seems like i should know.

Comment: So. You are right. `days[b]` is always greater than `smallest` (since `smallest == 0`) and when the if statement hits, it's going to set `largest` to `days[b]` . But then what happens? Smallest didn't change... so now you do the exact same comparison, and the same thing happens! This is also a problem in the loop below it.

Comment: I'm afraid not. This is a matter of a problem with your logic, not the loop. The loop is doing exactly what it's suppose to do. Let me suggest something. What if you changed smallest instead of largest? (I realize the naming is wrong there. But a name is just a way to reference the variable) So... if you change `largest = days[b]` to `smallest = days[b]` and put your print statement -outside- the for loop. What happens?

Comment: I would also recommend dealing with one loop at a time. (e.g. commenting out the second loop for now)

Comment: Also, Thanks @Makoto :) I didn't want to break the flow of the example code by talking about how the pieces of a for loop can be placed in different places. (Besides, who does that if we're not dealing with a while loop anyway? :P ) So I purposefully went over the basics of for loops. But yes, I am aware you can do something like.. `int i = 0; for(;;) { if(i >= something){ break; } else { stuff(); i++; } }`

Comment: I did that and it works! thanks, but now the other issue is the smallest print statement is now only printing the largest number possible

Comment: Ah ha! The plot thinkens. You see... both your for loops were suffering from the same problem. I have healed one of them. If you can figure out why that worked, you can heal the other. :)